# Spring MVC @CookieValue not finding cookie, but HttpServletRequest does

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I have a problem with retrieving cookie value in Spring MVC web app. Project configuration is pretty basic: Eclipse and Tomcat 8.0, full Spring 4.3.9 libs, nothing fancy.
I save cookies the normal way, that is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Main")
public String saveCookie(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.addCookie(new Cookie("testToken", "thisistesttoken"));

    return "Profile";
}
```

And it does actually saves the cookie. I check in Chrome and there it is, testToken with given value.
But when I try to retrieve it in my app using '@CookieValue' annotation, it gives me just the default value (or crashes when I don't declare default value):

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/Retrieve")
 public String loadCookiePage(@CookieValue(value="testToken",
  defaultValue="notmyvalue") String testToken) {

 System.out.println(testToken);

 return "SomeOtherPage";
}
```

The output is:

```
 notmyvalue
```

However, when I switch the code to 'HttpServletRequest' way of retrieving cookies, everything works:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/Retrieve")
 public String loadCookiePage(HttpServletRequest request) {

 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null) {
        Arrays.stream(cookies)
            .forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue()));
    }
 return "SomeOtherPage";
 }
```

The output:

```
(...other cookies)
testToken thisistesttoken
(...)
```

Now I really would like to stick to '@CookieValue' annotation, since code is more readable this way. Did anyone of you encounter this problem?
I tried it on different browsers, Tomcat's versions, etc., to make sure it's code related problem.